# Pagination with limited buttons

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using the following code for pagination of table.My table has more than 200 records,If I show more buttons for pagination that won't be fair.So is it possible to do pagination as shown in following image.(when i click next and previous buttons number only should change)
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var table =  $('#myTable');

                var max_size=userDetails.length;
                var sta = 0;
                var elements_per_page = 3;
                var limit = elements_per_page;
                pagination(sta,limit);
                function pagination(sta,limit){
                console.log(sta,limit);
                    for(var i=sta;i<limit;i++){
                    var tab='<tr><td>'+userDetails[i].Id+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Username+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Lastname+"\n"+'</td><td>'
                              +userDetails[i].Email+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Address+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Mobilenumber+"\n"+'</td><td>'
                              +userDetails[i].Age+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Gender+"\n"+'</td></tr>';

                     $('#myTable').append(tab)
                    }
                }
                $('#nextValue').click(function(){
                    var next = limit;
                    if(max_size>=next) {
                    def = limit+elements_per_page;
                    limit = def
                    table.empty();
                    if(limit > max_size) {
                    def = max_size;
                    }
                    pagination(next,def);
                    }
                });
                  $('#PreValue').click(function(){
                    var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);
                    if(pre>=0) {
                    limit = limit-elements_per_page;
                    table.empty();
                    pagination(pre,limit); 
                    }
                });
                 var number = Math.round(userDetails.length / elements_per_page);

                 for(i=0;i<=number;i++) {
                  $('.paginationList').append('<button class="btn">'+i+'</button>');
                 }
                 $('.paginationList button').click(function(){
                       var start = $(this).text();
                       table.empty();
                       limit = 3*(parseInt(start)+1) > max_size ? max_size: 3*(parseInt(start)+1)
                      pagination(start*3,limit); 
                 });
});
```

Complete code here:https://jsfiddle.net/t05bzecz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the changes. I had simply removed pagination button code.
In place of button I have a readonly textbox.

See changed code below

```js
var userDetails=[
{
"Id":"1",
"Username":"john",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"2",
"Username":"maro",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"3",
"Username":"maro",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"4",
"Username":"suja",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"5",
"Username":"nicco",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"6",
"Username":"maha",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"7",
"Username":"Dini",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"8",
"Username":"maha",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"9",
"Username":"maro",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
},
{
"Id":"10",
"Username":"krish",
"Firstname":"yyyyy",
"Lastname":"zzzzz",
"Email": "aaa@gmail.com",
"Address":"12345",
"Mobilenumber":"9876543210",
"Age":"20",
"Gender":"male"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var table =  $('#myTable');

    var max_size=userDetails.length;
    var sta = 0;
          var j=1;
    var elements_per_page = 3;
    var limit = elements_per_page;
         $('.paginationList').append('<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="btn">');
         $('.paginationList input').val(1);
    pagination(sta,limit);
    function pagination(sta,limit){
                console.log(sta,limit);
               
     for(var i=sta;i<limit;i++){
     var tab='<tr><td>'+userDetails[i].Id+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Username+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Lastname+"\n"+'</td><td>'
               +userDetails[i].Email+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Address+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Mobilenumber+"\n"+'</td><td>'
               +userDetails[i].Age+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Gender+"\n"+'</td></tr>';

      $('#myTable').append(tab)
     }
    }
    $('#nextValue').click(function(){
          
     var next = limit;
     if(max_size>=next) {
            j= eval(j+1);
            def = limit+elements_per_page;
            limit = def
            table.empty();
          
      if(limit > max_size) {
       def = max_size;
            }
            $('.paginationList input').val(j);
      pagination(next,def);
     }
    });
      $('#PreValue').click(function(){
          
     var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);
     if(pre>=0) {
          j = eval(j-1);
     limit = limit-elements_per_page;
     table.empty();
           $('.paginationList input').val(j);
     pagination(pre,limit); 
     }
    });
});
```

```css
.bgColor,.paginationList input:focus{
    background-color: #137dbd;
    color: #ffffff;
} 
#PreValue,#nextValue{
 border: none;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.paginationList input{
 border:1px solid  #137dbd;
 background: none;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
.padding{
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive">
 <table class="table  table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr class="bgColor">
       <td>Id</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Mobilenumber</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-6 padding pull-right">
 <button class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="nextValue">Next</button>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-12 paginationList padding">
 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-xs-6 padding pull-right">
 <button class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="PreValue">Pre</button>
 </div>
</div>
```